# Load MapLibre JSON URL to Maputnik editor

Tags: maplibre-gl, maputnik

I am setting up my own tile server. I am using MapLibre Martin tile server for this. Looking at its url schemes I dont see any where it returns .json URLs. I am essentially trying to load it as a data source in maputnik, so I can style its layers.
I do see JSON structure returned [here](https://mapapi.myholidaymap.com/2020-10-us-14). However, it does not load in maputnik.